# Confusing about slang - "ree" and "cue"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The sentence:

> *Cue incredible amounts of kobold ree.*

I understand word by word, but I can't understand a whole thing. It's easy for incredeble amouts of kobold, but "Cue" and "ree" make this hard to understand for me.

For some context, the kobold found his former dear pets been transmuted into something ugly.

And whole story. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the context, I would guess that "kobold ree" is a sound that kobolds make when they're in distress?

If that's true, then "cue" means "cue up", or "prepare to play" incredible amounts of kobold ree, since the player's character seems to be a kobold who is now very unhappy about his life choices.

Comment: I've a problem with compound all of this, cue up + incredible amounts of kobold + ree. As far as i can understand ree is literally angry whining about something. So how should he prepare to play (prepare to start) amout of whinning?

Comment: @Marader The interpretation of the sentence is just what was given. You may be confusing two different senses of the word *play* (*act out* and *produce sound*) Instead, consider: *Prepare yourself to listen to a lot of Kobold whining.* Or: *Brace yourself for a lot of Kobold whining.* Or even simply: *There was a lot of Kobold whining.*